# How do i resolve this aws sts issue on my cert-manager certificate

Tags: certificate, amazon-iam, amazon-eks, cert-manager

I am attempting to add a certificate to my kubernetes cluster with the help of cert-manager however i get the error below.

```
cert-manager-challenges  Error presenting challenge: error instantiating route53 challenge solver: unable to assume role: AccessDenied: User: arn:aws:iam::<ACCOUNT-ID>:user/route53-user is not authorized to perform: sts:AssumeRole on resource: arn:aws:iam::<ACCOUNT-ID>:role/route53role
```

**POLICY ATTACHED TO ROLE**

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "route53:GetChange",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:route53:::change/*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "route53:ChangeResourceRecordSets",
                "route53:ListResourceRecordSets"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:route53:::hostedzone/*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "route53:ListHostedZonesByName",
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

**ROLE TRUST RELATIONSHIP**

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "ec2.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are specifying `role` in the ClusterIssuer resource, you can try removing that line to prevent an AssumeRole.

```
    solvers:
    - dns01:
        route53:
          region: us-west-2
          # role: my-role
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be caused by a change in the behavior of sts:AssumeRole which is documented by AWS [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/announcing-an-update-to-iam-role-trust-policy-behavior/#:%7E:text=Previously%2C%20roles%20implicitly%20trusted%20themselves,referential%20role%20trust%20policy%20grants). As @Andrew pointed out, specifying a role causes an sts:AssumeRole action to occur, but if the current role does not have permission to assume the new role (or even the same role it is already) then that will fail.  We have found that we have to edit the trust relationship of the role to allow sts:AssumeRole to itself.  This used to be an implicit permission.  The documentation explains the change.